# Generating corrupted pdf files through batch job in AX 2009

Tags: pdf, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I got a problem with generating report pdf file through batch job. It works fine except when executed with a batch job (sometimes it works but most of time I have corrupted pdf files):

```
 while(qr.next())  //loop on my quotationId with some filters
        {
        salesQuotation = qr.get(tablenum(salesQuotationTable));
        filenamePDF = strfmt("%1%2",SalesQuotation.QuotationId,".pdf");

        permissionSetPDF =  new Set(Types::Class);
        permissionSetPDF.add(new FileIOPermission(filenamePDF,'w'));
        permissionSetPDF.add(new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop));
        CodeAccessPermission::assertMultiple(permissionSetPDF);

        report = new ReportRun(new Args(ReportStr(DevisContactBusinessV2)));
        report.query().interactive(false);
        report.report().interactive(false);
        report.args().caller(null);

        report.args().parm(SalesQuotation.QuotationId);

        report.printJobSettings().setTarget(PrintMedium::File);
        report.printJobSettings().format(PrintFormat::PDF);
        report.printJobSettings().warnIfFileExists(false);
        report.printJobSettings().fileName(strfmt("%1%2",path,filenamePDF));

        report.run();

        //tried to get around the file size problem by execute pdf file generation outside the loop
        fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(strfmt('%1%2',path,filenamePDF));
        length = fi.get_Length();

        if(length <= 1000)
            {
               info(strfmt("%1 %2","Quotation problem",SalesQuotation.QuotationId));
               this.OBRfixPDF(salesQuotation.QuotationId);
            }
        else
            {
                info(strfmt("%1 %2","Quotation OK:",SalesQuotation.QuotationId));
            }

        CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
    }
```

The generated files seem corrupted, they have a size of 1 ko and are not readable. There's no image inside the report, I'm using AX 2009 without SP1.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and believe it or not it had to do with fonts and font cache. I had to make a few changes, but the first thing you need to do is:

```
report.printJobSettings.format(PrintFormat::PDF_Embed_Fonts);
```

Then in the Class "ClassFactory" createViewer method add a boolean variable named "noFontCache" under the case "ReportOutputUserType::PDFEmbedFonts, change the code to be the following:

```
noFontCache = true;
return new PDFViewer(jobsCursor,pagesCursor,true,noFontCache);
```

Then in the class PDFViewer under the new mehtod, change the method signature to be:

```
public void new(PrintJobHeader _jobCursor, PrintJobPages _pagesCursor, boolean _embedFonts = false, boolean _noFontCache = false)
```

Then, just before the super call at the end of the method add the following code:

```
if(_noFontCache)
{
    pdfFontCache = new SysPdfFontCache();
}
else
{
     pdfFontCache  = infolog.getPdfFontCache();
}
```

This allows AX to generate a new font cache instead of using an existing one (which was generated by the user on their client machine which is now different from the server the that the batch job is running on).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with AX 2009 (pre rollup 7 or 8 I believe). There is a restriction put into place preventing PDFs being generated from the server if they contain images, because of a security concern.

I don't have much more information on it, but there is a hotfix for it, which you can find through CustomerSource. You can also find a link to it at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2011/09/19/you-cannot-print-images-on-batch-reports-now-you-can.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs if you use the Business Connector component from a Web service or from a Web application.
Here is the fix:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937345

Comment: Please don't only post link answers. Put the essential parts in your answer

Comment: it's a link to hotfix